# Foundation 5: how to remove inexplicable scrollbar

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

Even on a page almost totally blank, recently created, a scrollbar is appearing. I don't know from where it comes. Is it a bug? How can I remove it? (no overflow-y: hidden)

**Edited:**

It's a Rails app.

This is framework_and_overrides.css.scss generated by foundation-rails:

```
// Behold, here are all the Foundation components.
@import 'settings';
@import
"foundation/components/grid",
"foundation/components/alert-boxes",
"foundation/components/block-grid",
"foundation/components/breadcrumbs",
"foundation/components/buttons",
"foundation/components/dropdown",
"foundation/components/dropdown-buttons",
"foundation/components/forms",
"foundation/components/icon-bar",
"foundation/components/inline-lists",
"foundation/components/labels",
"foundation/components/pagination",
"foundation/components/panels",
"foundation/components/side-nav",
"foundation/components/sub-nav",
"foundation/components/tables",
"foundation/components/top-bar",
"foundation/components/type",
"foundation/components/visibility";

// override for the 'Home' navigation link
.top-bar .name {
  font-size: rem-calc(13);
  line-height: 45px; }
.top-bar .name a {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 15px; }

// THESE ARE EXAMPLES YOU CAN MODIFY
// create mixins using Foundation classes
@mixin twelve-columns {
  @extend .small-12;
  @extend .columns;
  }
@mixin six-columns-centered {
  @extend .small-6;
  @extend .columns;
  @extend .text-center;
  }
// create your own classes
// to make views framework-neutral
.column {
  @include six-columns-centered;
  }
.form {
  @include grid-column(6);
  }
.form-centered {
  @include six-columns-centered;
  }
.submit {
  @extend .button;
  @extend .radius;
  }
// apply styles to HTML elements
// to make views framework-neutral
main {
  @include twelve-columns;
  //background-color: #fff;
  }
section {
  @extend .row;
  margin-top: 20px;
  }

// Styles for form views
// using Foundation
// generated by the rails_layout gem
.authform {
  padding-top: 30px;
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.authform form {
  @include panel();
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.authform form a {
  font-size: rem-calc(13);
}
.authform form p {
  font-size: rem-calc(13);
}
.authform .form-group {
  // for Bootstrap, not used for Foundation
}
.authform .form-control {
  // for Bootstrap, not used for Foundation
}
.authform .checkbox {
  // for Bootstrap, not used for Foundation
}
.authform fieldset {
  @include panel();
}
.authform #error_explanation {
  @extend .alert-box;
  @extend .alert;
}
.authform #error_explanation h2 {
  font-size: rem-calc(16);
  color: white;
}
.button-xs {
  @extend .button;
  @extend .radius;
  @extend .tiny;
}
```

The others are the standard of the framework.

Comment: we would need to see your code, or a fiddle.

Comment: .row {
  max-width: 100%;
}

add the above and see if it fixes it!